# Cannot open Android Device Monitor on MacOS

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, android-device-monitor

I need to open Android Device Monitor but has been unable to due to this error

[image]

with the following in log

[image]

```
!SESSION 2018-01-17 15:54:32.643 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_TH
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/jitarinc/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault -keyring /Users/jitarinc/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-17 15:54:33.699
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).


at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

I have already tried updating the Java SDK and installing from Oracle. 
I have also already tried running it by terminal using Sudo

Comment: Please copy directly the error messages instead of screenshots